# What is the difference between Files.list and Files.walkFileTree and Files.walk with maxdepth = 1?

Tags: java, nio2, java.nio.file

If I want to do something with files only on the first level of the directory,
is there a difference between using `Files.list(...)` or `Files.walkFileTree(...)` or `Files.walk(...)`?

```
Files.walkFileTree(directory, Collections.emptySet(), 1, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        doSomething(file);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) {
        // log exc
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
});
```

versus

```
Files.list(directory)
    .forEach(path -> {
        try {
            doSomething(path);
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            // log exc
        }
    });
```

versus

```
Files.walk(directory, 1)
    .forEach(path -> {
        try {
            doSomething(path);
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            // log exc
        }
});
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using following code as test, I got the hang of the issue. The main difference between `walk*` and `list` is that `list(dir)` gives a stream of **files in the directory** `dir`, while both `walk*` method **walk the subtree** of its argument *including* the root of subtree—the directory itself.

The difference between `walk` and `walkFileTree` is that they supply different interfaces for walking the tree: `walkFileTree` takes `FileVisitor`, `walk` gives `Stream<Path>`.

```
public class FilesTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String pwd = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.out.println("Working Directory = " + pwd);
        Path dir = Paths.get(pwd);
        System.out.println("Files.walk");
        try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(dir, 1)) {
            stream.forEach(path -> FilesTest.doSomething("walk", path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logException("walk", e);
        }
        System.out.println("Files.walkFileTree");
        try {
            Files.walkFileTree(dir, Collections.emptySet(), 1, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
                @Override
                public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                    doSomething("visitFile", file);
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }

                @Override
                public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
                    logException("visitFile", exc);
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logException("walkFileTree", e);
        }
        System.out.println("Files.list");
        try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(dir)) {
            stream.forEach(path -> FilesTest.doSomething("dir", path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logException("dir", e);
        }
    }

    private static void logException(String title, IOException e) {
        System.err.println(title + "\terror: " + e);
    }

    private static void doSomething(String title, Path file) {
        System.out.println(title + "\t: " + file);
    }
}
```

Comment: > "**Skip the first element** of the stream to ignore the **root path**" (List only folders of certain depth using Java 8 streams) https://stackoverflow.com/a/51534978/9549068

Answer (score 4):

`Files.list` simply delegates to `Files.newDirectoryStream` and exposes the underlying `java.nio.file.DirectoryStream` as a `java.util.stream.Stream`, so their functionality is basically the same except that `Files.newDirectoryStream` allows you to pass an optional `DirectoryStream.Filter`.

`Files.walkFileTree` additionally exposes `BasicFileAttributes` (such as `lastModifiedTime`, `isRegularFile`, and `size`). If you are going to need these attributes, it could be more convenient (and possibly more efficient) to get them from `Files.walkFileTree` instead of looking them up separately.

Answer (score 2):

All these 3 solutions look correct, but it's better to use the simplest and the most readable way, so `Files.list()` looks natural to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that when using

```java
Files.list(directory)
    .forEach(path -> {
        try {
            doSomething(path);
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            // log exc
        }
    });
```

or

```java
Files.walk(directory, 1)
    .forEach(path -> {
        try {
            doSomething(path);
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            // log exc
        }
});
```

you MUST use try-with-resources if you don't want to introduce resource leak as stated in [Files.list() documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#list-java.nio.file.Path-):

> The returned stream encapsulates a DirectoryStream. If timely disposal of file system resources is required, the try-with-resources construct should be used to ensure that the stream's close method is invoked after the stream operations are completed.

so the best option should look something like:

```java
try(Stream<Path> list = Files.list(directory)) {
    list.forEach(path -> {
        try {
            doSomething(path);
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            // log exc
        }
    });
}
```