# List only folders of certain depth using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, directory, traversal

Considering there is the "new" [streams API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29575011/227821) in Java 8 I can use `Files.walk` to iterate over a folder. How can I only get the child folders of my given directory if using this method or maybe depth=2?

I currently have this working example, which sadly also prints the root path as all "subfolders".

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("/path/to/stuff/"))
     .forEach(f -> {
        if (Files.isDirectory(f)) {
            System.out.println(f.getName());
        }
     });
```

I therefore reverted to the following [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27940412/227821). Which stores the folders in memory and needs handling of the stored list afterwards, which I would avoid and use lambdas instead.

```
File[] directories = new File("/your/path/").listFiles(File::isDirectory);
```

Comment: May be count the number of backslash in the path in foreach loop and whatever having the depth as required can be filtered out

Comment: You could probably use [Files.walk with maxDepth](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-int-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) or [Files.walkTree with maxDepth](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.util.Set-int-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To list only sub-directories of a given directory:

```
Path dir = Paths.get("/path/to/stuff/");
Files.walk(dir, 1)
     .filter(p -> Files.isDirectory(p) && ! p.equals(dir))
     .forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.getFileName()));
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks

Comment: That only works for first depth. What if I want folders of depth 3 only?

Comment: This answer doesn't account for sub-directories at a specific depth.

Answer (score 17):

Here is a solution that works with arbitrary `minDepth` and `maxDepth` also larger than 1. Assuming `minDepth >= 0` and `minDepth <= maxDepth`:

```
final int minDepth = 2;
final int maxDepth = 3;
final Path rootPath = Paths.get("/path/to/stuff/");
final int rootPathDepth = rootPath.getNameCount();
Files.walk(rootPath, maxDepth)
        .filter(e -> e.toFile().isDirectory())
        .filter(e -> e.getNameCount() - rootPathDepth >= minDepth)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

To accomplish what you asked originally in the question of listing *"...only folders **of certain** depth..."*, just make sure `minDepth == maxDepth`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it deals with min and max depths

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of the second overload of the `Files#walk` method to set the max depth explicitly. Skip the first element of the stream to ignore the root path, then you can filter only directories to finally print each one of them.

```
final Path root = Paths.get("<your root path here>");

final int maxDepth = <your max depth here>;

Files.walk(root, maxDepth)
    .skip(1)
    .filter(Files::isDirectory)
    .map(Path::getFileName)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: 1+ for using `.skip()`

Comment: voted for skip()

Answer (score 2):

```
public List<String> listFilesInDirectory(String dir, int depth) throws IOException {
    try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(Paths.get(dir), depth)) {
        return stream
                .filter(file -> !Files.isDirectory(file))
                .map(Path::getFileName)
                .map(Path::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer would be considerably better if you were to add some explanatory text, as to how your code fixes the OP's problem(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with this:

```
private File getSubdirectory(File file){
    try {
        return new File(file.getAbsolutePath().substring(file.getParent().length()));
    }catch (Exception ex){

    }
    return null;
}
```

collect file:

```
File[] directories = Arrays.stream(new File("/path/to/stuff")
          .listFiles(File::isDirectory)).map(Main::getSubdirectory)
                                        .toArray(File[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Andreas‘s answer，u can also use Files.list instead of Files.walk

```
Files.list(Paths.get("/path/to/stuff/"))
.filter(p -> Files.isDirectory(p) && ! p.equals(dir))
.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.getFileName()));
```

Comment: `Files.list` is not recursive so you're basically limited to the depth of 1 only. Does not answer the original question of "*only folders of **certain** depth*".